# Pandas dataframe, extract consecutive rows of a column to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have, what seems to be a simple problem, but I cannot find an answer....

Assuming a pandas dataframe such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [4,5,6,7,8]})
```

In column `b`, I would like to extract a list containing the values of `n` consecutive rows starting `x` rows from the last row.

Assuming `n=3` and `x=1`, I would like to get:

```
list = [7,6,5] or list = [5, 6, 7]
```

I cannot figure out how to slice the relevant segment of dataframe to achieve this.

Any ideas?
Thank you !
Baka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_list = list(df['b'][-x-1:-x-n-1:-1])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you can use

forward direction `list(df['b'][x:(x+n)])` ==>> `[5,6,7]`

or

backward direction `list(df['b'][-(x)-1:-(x+n)-1:-1])` ==> `[7,6,5]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
n = -4
x = -1
lst = df.b.iloc[n:x].tolist()
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot get the 3 last rows with this if needed, can you? I mean if x = 0?

Comment: @Baka You can do it by leaving the space empty and not using `x`, like so: `df.b.iloc[n:].tolist()`